# Map nested object with Automapper in C#

Tags: c#, automapper

I use the latest version of AutoMapper 10.1.1 in my .NET Core project. I have a simple database for learning new words in a language I want to learn. I have the following tables:

- Words
- WordExamples
- WordExampleTranslation

In *Words* there is an ID for the word, and in the *WordExamples* I refer to this *ID* to link an example for that word. In *WordExampleTranslation* I have a reference to the *ID* of  *WordExamples* to have a translation in my language (just to understand what the example means). Every table has a lot of columns such as *CreatedAt*, *CreatedBy* and so on.

With Entity Framework Core, I read this data based on the word ID and I want to return to the UI only the essential fields.

```
public IQueryable<WordExample> GetAllByWordId(long wordId)
{
    return _db.WordExamples
                .Include(c => c.Word)
                .Include(c => c.Translations)
                .Where(r => r.WordId == wordId);
}
```

For that, I created 2 classes for basic information

```
public class BaseWordExample
{
    public long LanguageId { get; set; }
    public long WordId { get; set; }
    public string Example { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BaseWordExampleTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class BaseWordExampleTranslation
{
    public long LanguageId { get; set; }
    public long WordId { get; set; }
    public long DestinationLanguageId { get; set; }
    public string TraslationExample { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have my `MappingProfile` for *AutoMapper*

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<WordExample, BaseWordExample>()
            .ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<WordExampleTranslation, BaseWordExampleTranslation>()
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Then, I have an API

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync(long wordId)
{
    var list = _localDb.GetAllByWordId(wordId);
    var model = _mapper.Map<List<BaseWordExample>>(list);
    return model != null ? Ok(model) : NotFound();
}
```

I expect to receive a *json* mapped to the basic classes with all the data from *WordExamples* and also from its dependency table *WordExampleTranslation*. What I have is only the *WordExamples* values. The field *Translations* is not recognized by AutoMapper.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "language": 5,
    "wordId": 1,
    "example": "Eu parto para Inglaterra",
    "exampleHtml": "<i>Eu</i> <b>parto</b> para Inglaterra"
  }
]
```

Then, I tried to change the `MappingProfile` like the following

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<WordExample, BaseWordExample>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Translations, 
                       act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Translations))
            .ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<WordExampleTranslation, BaseWordExampleTranslation>()
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

but in this case I get this error

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation.
> ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<WB.Domain.Base.BaseWordExampleTranslation>
> WB.Domain.Base.BaseWordExample.get_Translations()'.

**Update**: I tried to convert the `IQueryable` result in a list

```
var list = _localDb.GetAllByWordId(wordId).ToList();
```

and then use Mapper but, again, I have only the main object. All the data from the dependency table *WordExampleTranslation* are ignored.

Comment: You should use `ProjectTo` instead.  See https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I saw that but it is only related to read a specific field into a DTO. In my case I like to have the full data in the class

Comment: No, it isn't! Maybe take the time to understand what those docs say. There are many examples available online.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync(long wordId)
{
    var list = _localDb.GetAllByWordId(wordId);
    var model = _mapper.Map<List<BaseWordExample>, List<WordExample>>(list);
    return model != null ? Ok(model) : NotFound();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I get this error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WB.Domain.WordExample>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WB.Domain.WordExample>`

Comment: Probably must match two types. Could you convert one of them?

Comment: Convert to `List` you mean?

Comment: Yes you could check it. Or make both of them IQueryable with `AsQueryable(IEnumerable)`

Comment: The function that reads data from the database already returns `IQuerable` and I have all the objects I expect in the `list` variable

Comment: So you should use Queryable Extensions. Read from docs https://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html